# FirestoreService collectionStream not returning value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a button with an `onPressed` function that returns `_shopActivatePage` function. It is meant to navigate to either `ShopActivatePage()` or `EmptyContent()`, depending on a `Future<bool>`. 
However, this function returns the else statement even if there's data in my stream.   Without the if else, this function works fine.

The code for the stream is:

```
  @override
  //print all docs from firebase collection
  Stream<List<Shop>> shopStream() => _service.collectionStream(
    path: APIPath.shops(uid),
    builder: (data, documentId) => Shop.fromMap(data, documentId),
  );
```

and the function is:

```
  void _shopActivatePage (BuildContext context) async{
    final db = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);

    if (await db.shopStream().isEmpty) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (context) => ShopActivatePage(),
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ));
    } else{
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (context) => EmptyContent(
          title: 'Shop activated',
          message: 'Your shop has been set up',
        ),
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ));
    }
  }
```

Thank you so much in advance and sorry if this is an amateur question. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: In this case I don't understand why you need a stream. Use a _service.collectionFuture. And the if((await db.shopStream()).isEmpty)

Comment: Hi Mario, I tried to implement _service.collectionFuture but it doesnt seem to be an existing method in Firestore Service

Comment: What is your @override ?? And What is _service? Did you create one like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I give you my FirestoreService. I thought you were using one like this.
So in your repository declare

```
final _service = FirestoreService.instance;
```

My FirestoreService :

```
class FirestoreService {
  FirestoreService._();

  static final instance = FirestoreService._();

  void setData({
    required String path,
    required Map<String, dynamic> data,
  }) {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    reference.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }

  Future<void> setDataWithAwait({
    required String path,
    required Map<String, dynamic> data,
  }) async {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    return reference.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }

  void updateData({
    required String path,
    required Map<String, dynamic> data,
  }) {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    reference.update(data).catchError((onError) {});
  }

  Future<void> updateDataWithAwait({
    required String path,
    required Map<String, dynamic> data,
  }) async {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    return reference.update(data).catchError((onError) {});
  }

  void deleteDoc({required String path}) {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    reference.delete().catchError((onError) {});
  }

  Future<void> deleteCollection({required String path}) async {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);

    final query = await reference.get();

    for (final doc in query.docs) {
      doc.reference.delete();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    }
  }

  Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>({
    required String path,
    required T Function(Map<String, dynamic>? data) builder,
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> Function(Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> query)?
        queryBuilder,
    int Function(T lhs, T rhs)? sort,
  }) {
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> query =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    if (queryBuilder != null) {
      query = queryBuilder(query);
    }
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>?>> snapshots =
        query.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((snapshot) {
      final result = snapshot.docs
          .map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data()))
          .where((value) => value != null)
          .toList();
      if (sort != null) {
        result.sort(sort);
      }
      return result;
    });
  }


  Stream<List<T>> collectionGroupStream<T>({
    required String path,
    T Function(Map<String, dynamic>? data)? builder,
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> Function(Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> query)?
        queryBuilder,
    int Function(T lhs, T rhs)? sort,
  }) {
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> query =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup(path);
    if (queryBuilder != null) {
      query = queryBuilder(query);
    }
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>?>> snapshots =
        query.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((snapshot) {
      final result = snapshot.docs
          .map((snapshot) => builder!(snapshot.data()))
          .where((value) => value != null)
          .toList();
      if (sort != null) {
        result.sort(sort);
      }
      return result;
    });
  }

  Future<List<T>> collectionFuture<T>({
    required String path,
    required T Function(Map<String, dynamic>? data) builder,
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> Function(Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> query)?
        queryBuilder,
    int Function(T lhs, T rhs)? sort,
  }) async {
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>?> query =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    if (queryBuilder != null) {
      query = queryBuilder(query);
    }
    final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>?> docs = await query
        .get()
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: timeOutSecond), onTimeout: () {
      throw Exception();
    });

    final result = docs.docs
        .map((e) => builder(e.data()))
        .where((element) => element != null)
        .toList();

    if (sort != null) {
      result.sort(sort);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```